# ASP.NET MVC OIDC - How to redirect to home controller and action when cookie/token expires

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, openid-connect

I am using OIDC to authorize users to gain access to an ASP.NET MVC application within my organization.

The problem I am having is I have the reply URL as the following `https://mywebsite.net/`.

Every time the cookie/token expires and the user navigates to a non-default controller `https://mywebsite.net/Home/Index` is met with this OIDC error.

> AADSTS50011: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application

Is there any way to catch this error without having to add all controller and actions to the reply URLs?

Could I say catch this error and try attempting to log the user in via Home/Index?

Here is my route config:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "FAT_Manager.Controllers" }
        );
}
```

Here is my OIDC code

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
        FATContext db = new FATContext();

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
            CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager(),
            //ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // we inject our own multitenant validation logic
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    // map the claimsPrincipal's roles to the roles claim
                    RoleClaimType = "groups",
                    NameClaimType = "preferred_username",
                },
                MetadataAddress = "MetaAddressHere",
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
                    {
                        // This ensures that the address used for sign in and sign out is picked up dynamically from the request
                        // this allows you to deploy your app (to Azure Web Sites, for example) without having to change settings
                        // Remember that the base URL of the address used here must be provisioned in Azure AD beforehand.
                        //string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Home", null, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                    // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                       
                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                        return authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                           code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer,

Changed this line:

```
context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path);
```

To:

```
context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action("Index", "Home", null, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme);
```